# Nuxt.jsで非同期に取得したデータを、コンポーネント内dataとVuexストアの両方に保存したい

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

ページ遷移時にサーバから取得したデータを、
以下に分けて保存したいと考えています。

- コンポーネント内data
- Vuexストア

Nuxt.jsの公式ガイドを読んだところ、片方のみに保存する場合であれば、
`asyncData`や`fetch`で対応すべきと理解できましたが、
両方に保存したい場合にはどうすべきか分かりませんでした。

暫定案として、

- `asyncData`内で、「コンポーネントのdata」に保存
- `mounted`内で、dataの「Vuexストア」に保存

を考えていますが、これ以外によい方法はありませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asyncData内で「Vuexストア」に保存も行えば良いと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。fetchはVuexストアにのみ保存する場合に利用し、dataコンポーネントまたは両方に保存する場合には、asyncDataを利用しようと思います。